# 2nd step never gets called inside fiber (synchronize.js)

Tags: node.js, synchronize

I'm trying to work with synchronize.js to run some functions that must be executed synchronously. 
I've read something about it [here](https://mixmax.com/blog/node-fibers-using-synchronize-js) and [here](http://alexeypetrushin.github.io/synchronize/docs/index.html).

To try it out, I've created the following code

```
var sync = require('synchronize');
var fiber = sync.fiber;
var await = sync.await;
var defer = sync.defer;

function function1(){
    console.log("Executing function 1")
}

sync.fiber(function() { 
console.log('Before');
var step1 = await(setTimeout(function1, 1000, defer()));
var step2 = console.log('After');
}); 

console.log('Outside');
```

Logic tells me the output should be

```
Before
Outside
Executing function 1
After
```

But what I get is

```
Before
Outside
Executing function 1
```

Somehow, step2 is not being executed and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used this plugin before but try this:

```
var sync = require('synchronize');
var fiber = sync.fiber;
var await = sync.await;
var defer = sync.defer;

function function1(callback){
    // defer expects this to be asynchronous (so it needs to execute a callback)
    console.log("Executing function 1")
    callback();
}

sync.fiber(function() { 
console.log('Before');
var step1 = await(setTimeout(function1, 1000, defer()));
var step2 = console.log('After');
}); 

console.log('Outside');
```

<strike>Basically I think calling `defer` prematurely (before the callback is executed) causes it to hang.</strike>

**Edit:**

After reading the documentation I now realize that `defer` creates a callback function. That would mean it's hanging because the callback it creates is never called. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly, I feel a little embarrased now that I know the answer but I couldn't get it before. I still need to get better at working with the async calls in node.